# Change all buttons background-color in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, color-picker

I have here a code which allows me to change the color of the buttons. Weird thing for me is that it only changes one button instead all of them. But I want to have it changed all of them at the same site. 
Here is a codepen code with HTML: https://codepen.io/akincakiner/pen/EExxMe

```js
/*Set your own color*/
var jscolor;
var defaultColor = (localStorage.getItem("color")) ? localStorage.getItem("color"): "#0078c0";

window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
function startup() {
  jscolor = document.querySelector(".jscolor");
  if (jscolor) {
    jscolor.value = defaultColor;
    jscolor.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
    jscolor.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
    jscolor.select();
  }
  refreshSidebar(defaultColor);
}

function updateFirst(event) {
  refreshSidebar(event.target.value);
}

function refreshSidebar(color) {
  var side = document.querySelector(".themecolor");
  var bgColor = document.querySelector(".bgcolor");
  var text = document.querySelector(".onlyTextColor");
  if (side, bgColor, text) {
    side.style.backgroundColor = color;
    bgColor.style.backgroundColor = color;
    text.style.color = color;
  }
}

function updateAll(event) {
  localStorage.setItem('color', event.target.value);
  $(".themecolor, .bgcolor, .onlyTextColor").each(function(index, element){
    if($(element).hasClass("onlyTextColor")){
      $(element).css('color',event.target.value)
    }
    else{
      $(element).css('background-color', event.target.value);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: there is no comments or any descriptions. How can some one know which function is doing what

Comment: whoops you're right! I will edit it.

Comment: also if you can put the corresponding HTML, it would nice

Comment: hope this helps: https://codepen.io/akincakiner/pen/EExxMe

Comment: seems to be working for me once I added jQuery library. Are you sure you included it?

Comment: this is the library i added to my page: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: weird thing what is happening that I did the same and the in the codepen it does work. But in my own html it simply doesnt work. Only the first button gets a color.

Comment: in your own HTML are you getting an error in the console like "`$` is not defined?"

Comment: this is the only error I get in my html: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at JQuery.js:141 AND Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null
    at drawImage (JQuery.js:181) But this is something else and not the color change code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, just write in jQuery - don't combine with native JS if possible. Otherwise you will confuse your learning of jQuery.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zurebutugi/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
    var defaultColor = (localStorage.getItem("color")) ? localStorage.getItem("color") : "#0078c0";

    function chColor(color){
      $(".themecolor, .bgcolor").css("background-color", color);
      $(".onlyTextColor").css("color", color);
      localStorage.setItem("color", color);
    }
  
    chColor(defaultColor);
  
    $("#theming-color").change(function(){
      chColor($(this).val());
    })
    .val(defaultColor)
    .css("background-color", defaultColor);

    
});
```

Comment: Okay but there is a little problem with this. This does work on the page itself. but not on other pages. Like if I want to have the buttons being red on all the pages

Comment: localstorage must be works in same domain too. open [example1](http://jsbin.com/hubicojafe/1/edit?html,js,output) then change color. after that open [example2](http://jsbin.com/zunizuzari/1/edit?html,js,output) you will notice if color in second page is same as your previous choosen

Comment: True but I see why this is happening. Open the first site. change the color. on the second side: delete the line: <input id="theming-color"> Now you will see that the colors doesn't change. which means that the site where you are in at needs to have the id:theming-color

Comment: And if you randomly add id="theming-color" somewhere then all the colors are changing

Answer (score 0):

Without the html part of your page we can only guess what is going on. But I think the problem is in this html part.

Because if I put your code into a test where the html part looks something like this, it works like expected.

```js
function updateAll() {
  //localStorage.setItem('color', event.target.value);
  $(".somebuttons, .bgcolor, .onlyTextColor").each(function(index, element){
    if($(element).hasClass("onlyTextColor")){
      $(element).css('color','red')
    }
    else{
      $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
}

$('#colorMyButtons').on('click', updateAll);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="colorMyButtons">color my buttons</button>
<br><br>
<button id="btn01" class="somebuttons">btn01</button><br>
<button id="btn02" class="somebuttons">btn02</button><br>
<button id="btn03" class="bgcolor">btn03</button><br>
<button id="btn04" class="bgcolor">btn04</button><br>
<button id="btn05" class="onlyTextColor">btn05</button><br>
<button id="btn06" class="onlyTextColor">btn06</button><br>
```

Comment: I probably added some more code when you was trying this. I appreciate it though. I have a codepen link where is my situation kind of:  https://codepen.io/akincakiner/pen/EExxMe I will try what you are doing now

Comment: In codepen when I add the library it works. But in my html page it simply doesn't which is very strange